# How do I manage multiple clients on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to Amazon AWS and as a freelancer I am not clear on how I would facilitate dozens of clients using AWS. I average 5 clients per month. How would I do billing and set up instances for multiple clients?  I have been using godaddy for a long time and they have a pro user dashboard that manages all of that.

Comment: Maybe you should ask to aws support...

Comment: I did and they promoted their management services but I wanted to know what freelancers are doing.

Answer (score 4):

You should create a separate AWS account for each client. If you are handling the AWS payments, then you could use AWS Organizations to combine the accounts into a single bill. You will be able to split the billing report into accounts to see exactly what each client owes you for AWS services.

This will also allow you to hand over an AWS account to a client, or provide their developers with access if they need it, without compromising your other clients in any way.

Comment: That makes sense, but I don't think I want to manage their bills. But that really helped me to clarify what I want to do, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are the **only person who can access the AWS services** (eg management console, create resources, etc), then @MarkB's suggestion is sound: Create separate AWS Accounts under an Organization, the the customers for their usage.

Another benefit of this method is that you might want to **charge your clients a fixed amount per month, or an *uplift*** (eg extra 20% on top of AWS costs) for your service of managing their account and taking care of payments.

If, however, **your clients have the ability to create resources under AWS**, you might want to have *them* setup the AWS accounts so that it **bills them directly**. This is because your clients might create resources that cost additional money and might then claim that they didn't realise the impact of what they were doing, thus leaving you with a bill that they don't want to pay.

Comment: A good warning! It is tricky. In the past I have had them set up their own account. I was just wondering what is possible with AWS that may offer more control. Thank you!